# "Exception: Argument cannot be null: buttons" with the ui.prompt commands. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to add a row to a named range in Google Sheets through the use of a menu that brings up a prompt with buttons. The button relating to the range I want to go to is clicked, values transferred over to script and used to add a row at the end of the range.

I have gotten the menu item to show up properly, and am trying to get the prompt portion to work. The error is on this code:

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.prompt('Choose Department', 'Departments', ui.ButtonSet.Screening_Packing_PadPrint_Embroidery_Labels_Shipping_Materials_Sullivan_Quality);
// The variable 'response' is the one that gives the error.
```

I have looked around and am not sure what the problem is. I think it might be too many button arguments, but I have not been able to find if there is a limit.
I'm new to GAS and still learning, so any help would be appreciated.

Link to the page:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10h5KH5IomMSYtp5yXznfrg1ql98mghr_zQoPA8xiRdQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Although I'm not sure about `ButtonSet.Screening_Packing_PadPrint_Embroidery_Labels_Shipping_Materials_Sullivan_Quality`, in the current stage, it seems that "Enum ButtonSet" has 4 values. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set) How about this?

Comment: Seems I can't add custom buttons to it after reading through that. I'll keep looking. I'm trying to stay out of HTML because I don't know anything about that code and still don't have a firm grasp of GAS either. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

If you want to use [Prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) in order to avoid writing HTML, you have to choose one of the 4 possible values in [Enum ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set), as mentioned [by Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334667/exception-argument-cannot-be-null-buttons-with-the-ui-prompt-commands-why#comment115505557_65334667):

- OK
- OK_CANCEL
- YES_NO
- YES_NO_CANCEL

You cannot add custom buttons if you use prompts. If you need custom buttons, you'd need to use [Custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), which require HTML.

#### Reference:

- [prompt(title, prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#prompttitle,-prompt,-buttons)